# Listar dados com Ajax e PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho a seguinte tabela

```
<?php foreach ($this->views->clients as $client): ?>
    <tr class="tr_<?= $client['id'];?>">
        <td><?= $client['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $client['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $client['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $client['nickname']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $client['hour_value']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $client['discount']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $client['date_pagment']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $client['cep']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></a></td>
        <td class="text-center"><a href="" id="<?= $client['id']; ?>" class="getId glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

nesta mesma página tem um `modal` que é um formulário que insere os `dados` que vão aparecer nesta tabela, gostaria de saber qual é a melhor forma de carregar estes `dados` dinamicamente com `AJAX`, gostaria também que os novos registros fossem exibidos no topo da tabela.

Código `AJAX` para inserir `dados`:

```
// Register and list clients script
 $(function() {
     $('#AjaxRequestClient').submit(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var form = $(this).serialize(); // Pode ser usado serializeArray()
         var request = $.ajax({
             method: "POST",
             url: "/registerClient",
             data: form,
             dataType: "json",
             success: function() {

             }
         });

         request.done(function(e) {
             $('#msg').html(e.msg);
             $('.alert').removeClass('fade').addClass('alert-danger');

             if (e.status) {
                 $('#AjaxRequestClient').each(function() {
                     $('.alert').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success');
                     this.reset();
                 });
             }
         });

         return false;
     });
 });
```

Comment: Qual código AJAX você já tem pronto até o momento?

Comment: Editei e coloquei o código ajax que insere os dados na tabela, queria que apos a inserir ele joga o novo registro la to topo..

Comment: eu sempre uso a primeira opção, com o success callback.

Answer (score 1):

Suponho que você esteja usando jQuery. Para colocar conteudo novo no topo da tabela basta usar a função [prepend](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_prepend.asp) (inserir conteudo no inicio de um elemento). Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
request.done(function(e){
        $('#msg').prepend(e.msg);
        //...
});
```

Dependendo de qual elemento tenha o id #msg, pode ter um resultado inesperado (caso esteja diretamente na tag table e o thead esteja incluso).

Comment: não entendi, se ele pode usar o success callback pra que usar o request.done?

Comment: acho que ele está usando para verificar se aconteceu algum erro na requisição (embora possa ser feito usando o callback error, como no success).